# Flow annotation issue for return function in React

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am having a slight issue getting this to work, and not throw a ton of linting errors. Apparently using "Function" is dangerous, so I've been using

() => mixed

Perhaps I am reading the docs incorrectly, but for something like this:
The following is throwing linting errors allover and just doesn't work.

```
class Foo extends Component {
   // skipping a bunch of React stuff
   // fake method for example sake
   myMethod = (cb: () => mixed = _.noop): () => mixed => {
     return cb;
   }

 }
```

Only this seems to work: BUT, I believe the docs said not to use it.

```
class Foo extends Component {
   // skipping a bunch of React stuff
   // fake method for example sake
   myMethod = (cb: Function = _.noop): Function => {
     return cb;
   }

 }
```

How can I set a return type as "function" and use default type as a "function" for function params?

Comment: so, I'd end up with:  myMethod = (cb: (Function) => mixed = _.noop): (Function) => mixed => { ???

Comment: What is the error you get? That seems fine to me.

Comment: @Kinduser Your example isn't the same type as the example though. I can't tell which case you're trying to replace. Your example either accepts a param that isn't needed, or returns `mixed` instead of a function returning `mixed`.

Comment: well, the example is suppose to show a function that takes another function, which has a noop as default.. AND I return a function. I was only using "mixed" becuse the docs suggested it.. but that is my issue.. I don't know how to achieve what i'm after.

Comment: As I said, what is the error you are getting? Your snippet as-is works fine: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVMCmAXMB9MAXjAG9UwwA7OOABwAoA6ZgQwCcBzAZwC4wBBNmxYBPADwBbAJYAPTABMAfAEo+ANzhT5pdBQC+qA6gDGMFly5gAYjQpkKYCSICyOABZxtxesYBGfemUiRUdZBSJ8Rmo6VTBA4NC5LxD7BzA2HABXNkowPwBucn1yAyA

Comment: mostly linting errors, nothing per se' that is an error. Just lint warnings. Let me check my linter to verify it is "indeed' an issue. Thanks, appreciate it.